# "The 'Query' and the 'InputFile' options are mutually exclusive" error running SqlAzureDacpacDeployment with sql file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to apply an Entity Framework Core migration script on my Azure SQL database.  I get my access token and then try to run the script.

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service connection name>'
    scriptType: 'ps'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $token= & az account get-access-token --resource=https://database.windows.net --query accessToken
      Write-Output("##vso[task.setvariable variable=sqlToken;]$token")

- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '<service connection name>'
    AuthenticationType: 'connectionString'
    ConnectionString: 'Server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=hrchangemanagement;Connection Timeout=30;'
    deployType: 'SqlTask'
    SqlFile: $(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\script.sql
    sqlAdditionalArguments: /AccessToken:$(sqlToken)
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

In the output of the `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment` task, I get this:

```
Starting: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment
==============================================================================
Task         : Azure SQL Database deployment
Description  : Deploy an Azure SQL Database using DACPAC or run scripts using SQLCMD
Version      : 1.234.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment
==============================================================================
Added TLS 1.2 in session.
Temporary inline SQL file: C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp94B2.tmp
Invoke-Sqlcmd -connectionString "**********"  -Inputfile "C:\Users\VssAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp94B2.tmp" 
Sql file: D:\a\1\a\script.sql
Invoke-Sqlcmd -connectionString "**********"  -Inputfile "D:\a\1\a\script.sql" /AccessToken:"<access token value>"
##[error]The 'Query' and the 'InputFile' options are mutually exclusive.Check out how to troubleshoot failures at https://aka.ms/sqlazuredeployreadme#troubleshooting-
Finishing: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment
```

In the output I see `Invoke-Sqlcmd` ran twice.  I don't know if that's expected or not?

I've read through the MS article on `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment` at least three times: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-azure-dacpac-deployment-v1?view=azure-pipelines

From discussion boards, it appears this error is more a syntax error than anything else.

- I checked for extra single quotes inside double
- I checked for extra spaces
- I tried using `AdditionalArguments` instead of `sqlAdditionalArguments` and that produced
  a login error `Login failed for user ''` which tells me it didn't pick up the access token.
- One MS discussion said there may be values cached after editing the task so it said to delete the task and rerun the pipeline.  I recreated the tasks and then ran again with no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the output I see Invoke-Sqlcmd ran twice. I don't know if that's expected or not?

It's correct behavior. The `SqlAzureDacpacDeployment` task first creates a temporary SQL file and executes it. This is done to set up the SQLCMD variables. Then it executes the actual SQL file you provided.

> ##[error]The 'Query' and the 'InputFile' options are mutually exclusive.

The error means you can’t use both at the same time. You have `SqlFile`(-inputfile) specified and `/AccessToken:$(sqlToken)` in `sqlAdditionalArguments`(-query). If you’re passing a query via -Query parameter and an input file via -InputFile parameter at the same time, you’ll need to choose one.

As per your steps, you're using `service principal` from service connection to run the sql script. It will fail as the service principal doesn't grant proper permission on the database.

To grant the permission for SP:

1. you need to connect the azure SQL with `Entra user`:
   [image]
2. Create user and assign role, the `SPN` is the `existing` service principal name which comes from service connection.

```
CREATE USER [SPN] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [SPN];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [SPN];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [SPN];
```

[image]

3. You can change `servicePrincipal` for AuthenticationType of the task.

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ARMConn4'
    AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
    ServerName: 'mysqlserver.database.windows.net'
    DatabaseName: 'db1'
    deployType: 'SqlTask'
    SqlFile: '**\script.sql'
    IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'
```

My pipeline result:

[image]

Created the new table from the script:

[image]

you can also check the [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/qtip-connect-to-azure-sql-db-using-entra-spn-service-principal/ba-p/4046781) for your reference.